# Bad file descriptor error [Errno 9]

Tags: python, server, client, descriptor

im trying to run the python file below, server and client
it supposed to create an http request with file data and when entering as a url in the client "127.0.0.1:8000" it sould get the data and run it
when im trying to run it im getting errno 9 bad file descriptor
ive tried running this before and it worked but now this...

```
"""
Developer: Roei Edri
File Name: httpServer.py
Exercise:  4.4
Date:      5.3.2018
"""

import socket
import os.path

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8000
ROOT_PATH = "C:" + os.path.sep + "webroot"


class httpServer(object):
    """
    Http server that supports html, js and css.
    """
    # Status Codes
    not_found = 'HTTP/1.1. 404 Not Found'
    forbidden = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
    moved_temporarily = "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"
    internal_server_error = "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

    def __init__(self, ip, port, root):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.root = root

    def initiate_connection(self):
        """
        Builds the connection between the client and server
        Runs through a loop which means it can try to connect again and 
again
        after failure
        """
        print("Initiating Connection...")

        # Opens a socket and connects to the client
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        server_socket.listen(1)
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

        # Entering a loop in order to be able to keep getting requests
        while True:
            print("Destination Address: " + str(address))
            request = self.get_request(client_socket)
            print(str(request))
            # Checks weither whether the request contains a string (url)
            if request:
                request = ROOT_PATH + os.path.sep + \
                request.replace("/", os.path.sep)
                response = self.send_response(request)

                print("trying to send response to client")
                try:
                    client_socket.send(response)
                except:
                    print("An error has occurred while sending the response 
to\
                    the client")
            # In case the request is invalid or empty
            else:
                if request == 0:
                    try:

  client_socket.send(self.internal_server_error.encode())
                    except:
                        print("An error has occurred while sending the response\
                        to the client")
                        break
                else:
                    break

            try:
                client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
            except:
                print("An error has occurred when trying to initiate 
connection\
                ")
                break

            # Closing connection
            server_socket.close()
            client_socket.close()
            print("Closing connection...")

    def get_request(self, client_socket):
        """
        Gets the request from the client
        In case of a non GET HTTP request, connection will be ended
        :return: string/int: url/0
        """
        try:
            client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            client_request_list = client_request.split(" ")
            print(client_request_list)
            # Checking weither the request is a valid GET HTTP request
            if (client_request_list[0] == "GET"):
                return client_request_list[1]
            if(client_request_list[2][:8] == "HTTP/1.1"):
                return client_request_list[1]

        except IndexError:
            print "Index error occured when trying to get the http request"
            return 0

    def send_response(self, file_path):
        """
        Gets the info from the request (the url) and returns a response
        :param file_path: string
        :return: tuple: (the file, the file extension)
        """
        if file_path == '/' or file_path == \
           (self.root + os.path.sep + os.path.sep):
            file_path = self.root + os.path.sep + "index.html"

        file_extension = file_path.split('.')[1]
        # Checking weither the file exist or not
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            file_data = self.get_file(file_path)
            response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'

            # Adding the headers
            response += "Content-Length: " + str(len(file_data)) + "\r\n"
            response += "Content-Type: " + \
                self.set_content_type(file_extension) + "\r\n\r\n"

            # Checking weither reponse is empty
            if response:
                response = "\r\n" + response.encode() + file_data
                return response
            else:   # In case the response has am unknown extension, it's 500
                return self.internal_server_error.encode()
        return self.not_found.encode()

    def set_content_type(self, file_ext):
        if file_ext == "html" or file_ext == "txt":
            return "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        elif file_ext == "jpg":
            return "image/jpeg"
        elif file_ext == "js":
            return "text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"
        elif file_ext == "css":
            return "text/css"

        return ""

    def get_file(self, file_path):
        """
        Gets a path to a file and returnes the contained data
        :param file_path: string
        :return: string: file_data
        """
        file = open(file_path, "rb")
        file_data = file.read()
        file.close()
        return file_data


def main():
    server = httpServer(IP, PORT, ROOT_PATH)
    while True:
        server.initiate_connection()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "httpServer.py", line 165, in <module>
  main()
File "httpServer.py", line 162, in main
  server.initiate_connection()
File "httpServer.py", line 48, in initiate_connection
  request = self.get_request(client_socket)
File "httpServer.py", line 93, in get_request
  client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
  raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error you received?

Comment: @CoreCreatives edited it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def initiate_connection(self):
    """
    Builds the connection between the client and server
    Runs through a loop which means it can try to connect again and again
    after failure
    """
    print("Initiating Connection...")

    # Opens a socket and connects to the client
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

    # Entering a loop in order to be able to keep getting requests
    while True:
        print("Destination Address: " + str(address))
        request = self.get_request(client_socket)
        print(str(request))
        # Checks weither whether the request contains a string (url)
        if request:
            request = ROOT_PATH + os.path.sep + \
            request.replace("/", os.path.sep)
            response = self.send_response(request)

            print("trying to send response to client")
            try:
                client_socket.send(response)
            except:
                print("An error has occurred while sending the response to\ the client")
        # In case the request is invalid or empty
        else:
            if request == 0:
                try:
                    client_socket.send(self.internal_server_error.encode())
                except:
                    print("An error has occurred while sending the response\to the client")
                    break
            else:
                break

        # Closing connection
        client_socket.close()
        print("Closing connection...")
        try:
            client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
        except:
            print("An error has occurred when trying to initiate connection")
            break
```

Try this for initiate_connection function. You were closing client connection right after you accept it and then trying to read from it.

Comment: the code you added just says there is an error instead of letting it crash

Comment: It is working when I am running it. Make sure you have copied the exact code and if there is still error please paste that error here again.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/httpServer.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/httpServer.py", line 162, in main
    server.initiate_connection()
  File "C:/httpServer.py", line 48, in initiate_connection
    request = self.get_request(client_socket)
  File "C:/httpServer.py", line 93, in get_request
    client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor @serbia99

Comment: it works for the first time but when trying to reloads it gives the same error

Comment: One more thing. In main function you dont need to call server.initiate_connection inside a while loop. You just need to call it once. That might solve your error.